# How to print multiple inputs that are gathered into a dictionary horizontally

Tags: python

Im trying to figure out how to print multiple inputs from one dictionary. The way i have it, it only prints the last input sequence instead of printing all three inputs.

For reference:

The program asks for 3 inputs:name, count, and price. It then asks if you want to enter more with the usual y or n input and then you put in another 3, so on and so forth.

However, the print() will only print the last 3 inputs instead of all 3 sets.

What i have looks like this

```
input name
input count
input price
input more? y or n
a = {name:count}
d = {name:price}
print(a)
print(d)
```

output

```
'name',count
'name',price
```

but it should look like

```
{'name',count 'name',count 'name',count}
{'name',price 'name',price 'name',price}
```

is there a function i need to put on the print functions like print a.function()

or is it something in the formatting of the dictionary?

(edit:sorry this board has weird mechanics)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the [editing guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format your question. Also, suggest reading this help page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Could you provide your code and some actual input/output?  It looks like you're kind of paraphrasing what the program does instead of showing an actual example.  Just copy and paste your code, and the terminal output from running it.  (As text, not as screenshots.)

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused why you want to print same key value pair 3 times in one line. However if you really need that you can print

```
print(a,a,a)
print(d,d,d)
```

You cant create a dict with duplicate keys, but one key can have multiple values like

```
a = {name: [count, price]}
```

And I think most logical would be

```
a = {name: name, count: count, price: price}
print("name ", a[name], ", count ", a[count], ", price ", a[price])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ask_questions(name_list, count_list, price_list):
    name_list.append(input("name: "))
    count_list.append(input("count: "))
    price_list.append(input("price: "))

name_list = []
count_list = []
price_list = []

While input("more? y or n: ") == "y":
    ask_questions(name_list, count_list, price_list)

a = dict(zip(name_list,count_list))
d = dict(zip(name_list,price_list))
print(a)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out and forgot to come back. All I had to do was **ADD** the value to the key.

So it would be like:

```py
a[name]= count

d[name]= price
```

This gave me the loops I needed to fill out the whole thing.